# Force annotation line to connect xy and xytext coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

As described in the title, I would like to draw an annotation line that connects the annotation point (`xy`) with the text anchor point (`xytext`).

When the text is horizontally aligned to the center, I get the desired behavior. For instance, consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate('some text', xy=(5, 0), xytext=(5, -3), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), 
             fontsize=6, va='top', ha='center', xycoords='data', textcoords='data')

# Additional code for illustration purposes
plt.plot([5, 5], [0, -3], 'r--')
plt.scatter([5], [0], color='red', label='xy point')
plt.scatter([5], [-3], color='blue', label='xytext point')

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image:

[image: Example ok]

As soon as the horizontal alignment changes, for instance:

```
plt.annotate('some text', xy=(5, 0), xytext=(5, -3), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), 
             fontsize=6, va='top', ha='right', xycoords='data', textcoords='data')
```

I get the following undesired result (I would like the annotation line to remain vertical):

[image: Example wrong]

Looking at the documentation of the `plt.annotate` function, I could not find any option that allows the desired result to be achieved. Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior other than plotting the line and the text separately?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `relpos` key inside `arrowprops`...

`arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", relpos=(1., 1.))`

[image]